# One way data binding on 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On my registration form, I have  **firstname**, **lastname**, and **displayname** fields. When the **firstname** is updated, I want that value to reflect in the **displayname** field (should that field not already have a value).

I have set the update to occur on blur, and when I inspect the element directly for **displayname**, I see the *value* attribute set to the **firstname** value. However, that doesn't appear to reflect on screen or in the model. I am sure it's because that field is going off of `user.displayname` (which is initially empty).

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <form ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="Firstname"  ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastname" placeholder="Lastname" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.displayname" placeholder="Display"  value="{{user.firstname}}"/>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("RegisterCtrl", ["$scope" ,function ($scope) {
        $scope.user = {};
    }]);
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbqs7xcj/

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT**

One solution I came up with was `$watch`ing for a change on the `firstname` field, and then setting the `displayname` accordingly if the value doesn't already exist. However, I do not believe this to be the "solution" as I am sure there's a more efficient way of doing this.

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("RegisterCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        displayname: "",
        email: "",
        password: ""
    };

    // Set the firstname as the display name if it's empty
    $scope.$watch("user.firstname", function () {
        if ($scope.user.displayname.length === 0) {
            $scope.user.displayname = $scope.user.firstname;
        }
    });
}]);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbqs7xcj/7/

Answer (score 0):

remove `ng-model` directive in `input` display

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="Display"  value="{{user.firstname}}"/>
```

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbqs7xcj/2/)

if you are using `ng-model` angular try to find the value of that model name, so textbox is not updating because there is no value for that model name `user.displayname`.

Comment: That does update it. However, I want the `displayname` to be part of the model. When the user comes to the form, upon filling out the `firstname` field, I would like that value to be set to `displayname`. Of course, the user can change the `displayname` if they don't prefer it to be their first name. Likewise, if `displayname` already has a value, any changes to `firstname` should not overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative coud be by triggering and watch mouse event on first input.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-mouseleave="checkDisplayName($event)" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/darul75/mbqs7xcj/9/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I don't know that triggering a mouse event would be accurate, especially since forms are often navigated via the keyboard (`tab`). As for what I have come across so far, `$watch` seems to be my better solution at the moment.